# ng-if displaying both the div elements

Tags: angularjs

There are 2 div tags, i want to display only 1 based on value of SelectedVariant.InCart.

Code is as follows:

```
<div ng-if="1==0">
    <a class="btn btn-success btn-md" ng-click="AddToCart(product.ProductID, SelectedVariant.VariantID)">Add to Cart &nbsp;
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> 
    </a>
</div>



<div ng-if="1==1">

    <a class="btn btn-default btn-xs" ng-click="PlusItem(product.ProductID, SelectedVariant.VariantID)">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> 
    </a>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info disabled">{{3+2}} in cart</button>


    <a class="btn btn-default btn-xs" ng-click="MinusItem(product.ProductID, SelectedVariant.VariantID)">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span> 
    </a>
</div>  


        <a class="btn btn-default btn-xs" ng-click="MinusItem(product.ProductID, SelectedVariant.VariantID)">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span> 
        </a>
    </div>
```

But it displaying both the div elements. Can someone help me what is the issue?

Comment: whats `SelectedVariant.InCart.` ?

Comment: Its a element in ng-repeat loop

Comment: can u post the code for `ng-repeat` ?

Comment: Its not even working with 1==1 and 1==0, Please see updated post.

Comment: angular version is 1.0.7

Comment: thats the case upgrade the angular version and your code will work :). because AngularJS first added the ngIf directive in 1.1.5

Comment: Working Now!!!!! Thanks a lot. Please post a answer. i will accept that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your angular version is `1.0.7`. directive `ng-if` is not in this version of angular.
its introduce in angular 1.1.5

check it in angular under `Directives` topic [change log](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#115-triangle-squarification-2013-05-22)

```
AngularJS first added the ngIf directive in 1.1.5
```

please update the angular version and that will solve your problem. :)